# sphinxsearch: ? signs instead of non-latin characters

Tags: sphinx

I have an "?" (question sign) instead of non-latin characters in search results. I have sphinx 2.0.3 and latest Debian. Not the first time working with the Sphinx, but this problem is the first time. Encoding and database connection fully in UTF:

```
character set client utf8
character set connection utf8
character set database utf8
character set results utf8
character set server utf8
character set system utf8
collation connection utf8_general_ci
collation database utf8_general_ci
collation server utf8_general_ci
```

In sphinx config:

```
sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

In index section of sphinx config:

```
charset_type = utf-8
charset_table = 0..9, A..Z->a..z, _, a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sphinx doesnt give you text. It only gives you document IDs in search results. ... So the problem  is not with sphinx, but how you are retrieving results from your database. You need to give more details of you setup for more detailed help.

Comment: Sphinx indexer retrieves content that you described in index section of config. It stored not only id. About database - i described above that all variables set to utf and my database and tables are stored in utf.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sql_query_pre = SET CHARACTER SET utf8 use:

> sql_query_pre     = SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8